# Facing concurrency issues with Go sync maps

Tags: go, concurrency, hashmap, synchronization

I am having problems with Go's `sync.Map`. Below are the details:

I created a global sync map like:

```
var MySyncGlobalMap = sync.Map{}
```

and on an event I populate this map with the intended structure as 
`map[int64]map[string]interface{}`. So basically I want to populate the **sync map** with key as `int64` and value as another **sync map** of structure `map[string]interface{}`. Below is how I populate the map:

```
//below is the innerSync map. recSet is returned from DB call in the format : []map[string]interface{}
var innerSyncMap = sync.Map{}
for _, record := range recSet {

    sKey := record["key"].(string)
    value := record["value"]
    innerSyncMap.Store(sKey, value)
}
MySyncGlobalMap.Store(jobID, innerSyncMap)
```

Now there will be multiple threads which will be accessing this map and do some operations. There will be constant updates to the inner sync map. Once the processing is done on the key of the inner sync map, that key will be deleted from that map.

I will know that a job is complete once the inner sync map becomes empty.

Now since there are multiple threads accessing this map I receiving a panic:

> Fatal error: concurrent read and write

I am still wondering that even after using **sync map** I am facing this issue.

Can any one point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a code sample showing your error. Seems like you are creating normal maps (e.g. with `make(map[string]interface{}`) and accessing them in a concurrent manner.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani updated the question.

Comment: Is `recSet` shared between some goroutines by any chance? Try to run your code like `go run -race main.go` to get stack traces of where you are concurrently accessing a map.

Comment: Use the race detector. The sync.Map doesn’t magically make its contents safe for concurrent reads and writes

Comment: Show us the part that does the `delete()`. Pay attention to that part. I bet you will find the problem yourself right in there...

Comment: thanks for taking time to respond. I figured out the problem with the code. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem with the code was. I used the sync.Map as Value type instead of pointers.

So, I was making copies of the underlying mutexes. And on read/write operations the lock was on the copy instead of original mutex.

Changing the map to use pointers solved the problem.